# What's the most efficent way to populate an a property of an array of objects with a larger array with data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a small array of objects with properties, like so:

```
  [
    {
      topicName: 'Clicks',
      topic: 1,
      dates: [ <PLACE VALUES HERE> ],
    },
    {
      topicName: 'Cost',
      topic: 2,
      dates: [ <PLACE VALUES HERE> ],
    },
  ];
```

Then I have a large array of objects that I wish to extract some of the properties from in to the above dates array.
Here's what the data I wish to extract from:

```
[
    {
      "date": "2014-02-01",
      "device": "Computer",
      "match-type": "NA",
      "clicks": 66,
      "revenue": 1037,
      "conversions": 2,
      "cost": 284.35,
      "impressions": 5330,
      "ROI": 3.64691401441885
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-02-01",
      "device": "Tablet",
      "match-type": "NA",
      "clicks": 38,
      "revenue": 587,
      "conversions": 2,
      "cost": 194.01000000000005,
      "impressions": 1934,
      "ROI": 3.025617236224936
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-02-02",
      "device": "Tablet",
      "match-type": "NA",
      "clicks": 40,
      "revenue": 587,
      "conversions": 2,
      "cost": 190,
      "impressions": 1934,
      "ROI": 3.025617236224936
    },
  ]
```

Now I need the data from all of the members of the last array and insert that releveant data for the particular object in the first array (totalling where necessary), like so:

```
  [
    {
      topicName: 'Clicks',
      topic: 1,
      dates: [
        {
          date: '2014-02-01',
          value: 104
        },
        {
          date: '2014-02-02',
          value: 40
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      topicName: 'Cost',
      topic: 2,
      dates: [
        {
          date: '2014-02-01',
          value: 284,3519401
        },
        {
          date: '2014-02-02',
          value: 190
        }
      ],
    },
  ];
```

The target is the latest version of Chrome and I'm using Webpack with Babel so all the latest stuff is available.

Assuming the last dataset can be pretty large, what's the most efficient way to go about this?

[EDIT]

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
const dataAdapter = rawData => {
  const topics = ['clicks', 'revenue', 'cost', 'roi'];
  const topicsData = topics.map((topic, index) => {
    const thisTopic = {};

    thisTopic.topicName = topic;
    thisTopic.topic = index;
    thisTopic.dates = [];

    return thisTopic;
  });

  const convertedData = topicsData.map(topicData => {
    const thisTopic = topicData;
    const map = new Map();

    rawData.forEach(elem => {
      map.set(elem.date, (map.get(elem.date) || 0) + elem[[thisTopic.topicName]]);
    });

    thisTopic.dates = Array.from(map);

    return thisTopic;
  });

  return convertedData;
};
```

Thanks,

/J

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: Libraries like underscore.js and lodash are the easiest ways to do things like this.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built into ES6 for this kind of processing. You have to use a loop of some kind, but those libraries can automate it pretty nice ly.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object as reference to the wanted keys and date. Then iterate data and check if a reference to a result set exists. If not, create a new result set.

```js
var result = [{ topicName: 'Clicks', topic: 1, dates: [], }, { topicName: 'Cost', topic: 2, dates: [], }],
    data = [{ date: "2014-02-01", device: "Computer", "match-type": "NA", clicks: 66, revenue: 1037, conversions: 2, cost: 284.35, impressions: 5330, ROI: 3.64691401441885 }, { date: "2014-02-01", device: "Tablet", "match-type": "NA", clicks: 38, revenue: 587, conversions: 2, cost: 194.01000000000005, impressions: 1934, ROI: 3.025617236224936 }, { date: "2014-02-02", device: "Tablet", "match-type": "NA", clicks: 40, revenue: 587, conversions: 2, cost: 190, impressions: 1934, ROI: 3.025617236224936 }],
    hash = { clicks: { _: result[0].dates }, cost: { _: result[1].dates }, };

data.forEach(function (o) {
    ['clicks', 'cost'].forEach(function (k) {
        if (!hash[k][o.date]) {
            hash[k][o.date] = { date: o.date, value: o[k] };
            hash[k]._.push(hash[k][o.date]);
            return;
        }
        hash[k][o.date].value += o[k];
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I see room for improvements in my own function :) I'm looping over the large datset for every topic - I should do it the other way around obviously... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in `data` variable and topics are in `topics` variable. This solution uses only javascript builtin objects.

```
const getPropDateMap = (obj, prop) => obj
  .reduce((accObj, item) => {
    return Object.assign(accObj, {
      [item.date]: item.clicks + (accObj[item.date] || 0)
    })
  }, {})

topics.forEach(topic => {
  topic.dates = Object
    .entries(getPropDateMap(data, topic.topicName.toLowerCase()))
    .map(entry => ({date: entry[0], value: entry[1]}))
})
```